# Questions about eSport competition prizes

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

A user recently asked a [question about gaming competition prizes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243960/rocket-league-competition-prizes). The question strikes me as off-topic, since it's not actually related to the game itself. The only other meta question I could find about esports ([link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/are-esports-related-questions-permitted)) seems to lean toward saying that questions about the competition itself are off-topic. Lastly, the answers to the question could become outdated as soon as there is another competition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an issue with objective questions about eSports league structure, prizes, rules, etc. People who play games are the same people who are entertained by watching them, so our expertise inherently gives us expertise in eSports, as a community.

This is definitely not the place for discussion of current events, roster changes, predictions, or general fan activities, though. We are, first and foremost, a Q&A site.

Questions about how the game is played at a professional level are decidedly on topic, because they're just at the top end of the spectrum of questions about gameplay. Questions about why a skilled player or team used a specific strategy are *good* subjective questions, because a good answer can be backed up with analysis, details, and examples.

This answer is a little broader than the question you asked, but the point is this: I think **eSports content is on topic**, so long as it meets our other strict requirements for questions in general.